# How to create an admin mixin for common/abstract model in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am creating a multi tenant app and have the following abstract class that all relevant tenant specific models inherit from:

```
class TenantAwareModel(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

When registering models in the Django admin, I want to keep my code DRY and not have to add 'tenant' to every single search_fields, list_display, list_filter etc so I tried creating a super class to inherit from.

```
class TenantAwareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    # change_form_template = "admin/professional_enquiry_change_form.html"
    search_fields = ('tenant__id', 'tenant__name', 'tenant__domain',)
    list_display = ('tenant',)
    list_filter = ('tenant',)
```

And then trying to inherit that in the registration of the other models. E.g.

```
class UserAdmin(TenantAwareAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin ):
  ...
```

This approach matches the way the TenantAwareModel works.

```
class TenantAwareModel(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class User(AbstractUser, Uuidable, Timestampable, TenantAwareModel):
   ...
```

and it is of course giving me:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model TenantAwareModel is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.
```

Does anybody know the proper way to do this to avoid all the duplicated code?

Comment: How did you register the model for `TenantAwareAdmin`?

Comment: It's not registered. My idea was that given it was inherited by the tenant-specific models e.g. UserAdmin the registration of admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin) would do it

Comment: If you used `User` to register, can you try changing the order of the classes by keeping `AbstracUser` to the right? Like: `class User(Uuidable, Timestampable, TenantAwareModel, AbstractUser)`

Comment: Also, you might want to just extend django's `UserAdmin` with your `TenantAwareAdmin`. So import `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin`, then define something like: `class MyCustomUserAdmin(TenantAwareAdmin, UserAdmin):`

Comment: That only works for the User model. I will eventually have around 15 tenant-specific models of my own.

Answer (score 3):

The `Meta` class and `abstract=True` can only be defined in the model definition, not in the `ModelAdmin`.

The `TenantAwareModel` is an abstract model that allows you to avoid repeating the common fields in the definition of others models, but you can't register a abstract model in the admin site. The abstract model is not related with any table, its only task is to be a base from which inherit in other models that will represent tables(not abstract models) and which will be able to be registered in the admin site.

To avoid repeat the same fields in search_fields, list_display, etc, you should create a mixin like this:

```py
class TenantAwareAdminMixin:
    search_fields = [..., ...]
    list_display = [..., ...]
    ...
```

and inherit from this

```py
class UserAdmin(TenantAwareAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

But there is a problem... If you override some field defined in the `TenantAwareAdminMixin`, this will overwrite the value provided by the mixin forcing you to explicitly add the inherited values plus those new values, like this:

```py
class UserAdmin(TenantAwareAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = TenantAwareAdminMixin.list_display + ['new_value']
    ...
```

It is possible to obtain a similar result by overriding the [get_list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display), etc. methods.

Comment: It works. Thanks very much. The order being rigid is a minor annoyance but I can live with it.